# Replace every nth '\n' in a string

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to replace a bunch of \n from a string, with whitespace and '//', but not ALL \n in the string.

Luckily for me, there's a pattern: Every fourth \n should **not** be removed.

Example:

```
\n jack ryan
\n policeman and pony enthusiast
\n german 
\n john anderson <--- don't remove this \n
\n fisherman
\n swedish 
\n barack putin <--- don't remove this \n
\n french
\n programmer
```

Output:

```
jack ryan // policeman and pony enthusiast // german
john // fisherman // swedish
barack // french // programmer
```

I've looked for a simple reg ex solution, but I haven't found what I need.

I hope someone can help!

Comment: Are these actual `\ ` and `n` characters or do you mean new line?

Comment: That's not a job for regex: split on '\n' and when you loop to re-constract add '\n' after every third token

Comment: I mean a new line tenub! Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input looks a little funny to me, but this would accomplish what you're asking:

```
input = '\n jack ryan \n policeman and pony enthusiast \n german \n john anderson \n fisherman \n swedish \n barack putin \n french \n programmer'

# Split on '\n':
lines = input.splitlines()

# Remove the first empty line:
lines = lines[1:]

output = ''
step_size = 3
for i in range(0, len(lines), step_size):
    output += '//'.join(lines[i:i + step_size]) + '\n'

print output
```

Output:

```
 jack ryan // policeman and pony enthusiast // german
 john anderson // fisherman // swedish
 barack putin // french // programmer
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ford, this did exactly what I needed. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a regular expression by capturing groups followed by newlines:

```
import re
re.sub(r"([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)(\n?)", r"\1 // \2 // \3\4", s)
```

Comment: Nice. Tested this on my input and got: `'\n jack ryan  //  policeman and pony enthusiast  //  german \n john anderson  //  fisherman  //  swedish \n barack putin  //  french  //  programmer'`

Comment: Per @tenub are those meant to be the actual characters '\n' or newlines? If you want to strip out the characters '\n', add '\\n' before each capture group in the pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your help tcarobruce